# Obscure Text Makes Backspace Remove Two Characters at a Time

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard

I am developing an app in Flutter. The app works without an issue in iOS and seems to work correctly with the Swiftkey Keyboard, but I am experiencing issues with the gBoard and the Samsung Keyboard.

When I set the `obscureText` value to `true` for a `TextField` or a `TextFormField` the backspace button on the keyboard removes two characters at a time. When the `obscureText` field is `false` then it works properly. Additionally, I can have the `obscureText` field set to `true` and it will work fine if I am using the Switkey Keyboard.

I have looked all over and cannot find anything related to this, so I am stumped. I have tried reverting my screen to absolute barebones code to determine if there was a configuration issue or possibly a dependancy issue, but the issue still persists.

Here is the TextFormField widget that is the culprit:

```
TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: textSizeLarge,
                            color: t12_text_secondary
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Hours...',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.access_time,
                          color: t12_text_secondary,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: textSizeLarge,
                          color: t12_text_color_primary,
                          fontFamily: fontRegular,
                          height: 1.5
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if(value.isEmpty){
                          return "Date Required";
                        }else if(!helpers.isDouble(value)){
                          return "Value must be a number";
                        }
                        else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely related to [Flutter Issue 70744](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70744) and other similar issues.

There have been a few `TextInputType` bugs recently, possibly as the SDK is tweaked to support Web, Linux and Windows release targets.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will look into this Flutter issue. I have recently noticed that this bug has appeared on another flutter project of mine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem when i was using the 'beta' flutter channel. It was fixed after i changed to 'stable' channel. I think this problem is still a bug in the 'beta' channel.

You can check your channel by typing 'flutter --version' in terminal.

If it's not 'stable' channel, you can change it by typing 'flutter channel stable' in terminal.

Comment: I haven't worked on this app in a while, so I haven't been able to give the other answer a try yet either. When I play around with it next, I will give both of these a try. Thanks for the tip.